# Два раза показывается реклама

Tags: android

Воспользовавшись предложенным в другом вопросе ответом решил отображать рекламу с задержкой в 10 секунд. Написал так, но после закрытия рекламы (межстраничное), через некоторое время опять появляется. Почему так?

Вот код, в методе onCreate прописал его

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Для adMob
    private InterstitialAd adMob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!isShow) {
                    createAds();
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

    /*Проверка загрузки объявления adMob*/
    public void displayAdMob() {
        if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
            adMob.show();
            isShow = true;
        }
    }
    /*Проверка загрузки объявления adMob*/

    private void createAds() {
        /*Создаем межстраничное объявление adMob*/
        adMob = new InterstitialAd(this);
        adMob.setAdUnitId("идентификатор");
        // Создаём запрос к AdMob
        AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        // Начинаем загружать объявление
        adMob.loadAd(adRequesti);
        adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                displayAdMob();
            }
        });
        /*Создаем межстраничное объявление adMob*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. активность запускается, спустя 10 секунд происходит показ рекламы, ты её закрываешь, ничего не делаешь и реклама показывается еще раз?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Вроде как в самом вызове ничего криминального нет. А где создаешь Hander? Давай больше кода

Comment: обновил вопрос. Оставил только те методы, которые нужны для вывода рекламы

Comment: isShow = false; удали из хендлера

Comment: Убрал. Все равно показывает повторно рекламу

Comment: Очень странно. Такой вызов хендлера просто не может отработать более одного раза. Значит onCreate вызвывается несколько раз. Сделай вывод лога перед созданием хендлера и внутри него и посмотри че в консоли

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.

Comment: У меня в методе onCreate есть еще такой код, который все время выводит небольшой баннер Admob. Может из-за этого и межстраничное выводится повторно AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59272/discussion-between-mifkamaz-and-webeus).

Answer (score 0):

В `onCreate` надо добавить проверку переменной, которая принимает значение `true` или `false`, в зависимости от того, была уже показана реклама или нет.

Видел код на одном сайте, которую эту проблему обходил созданием в `onCreate` таймера.

Comment: попробовал так, но не сработало: В метод displayAdMob после adMob.show(); добавил isShow = true;  А в onCreate написал так    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!isShow) {
                    createAds();
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        }, 10000);

Comment: Я вспомнил, как там было сделано. Зачем таймер. В `onCreate` не нужно ничего писать подобного. Нужно в основном теле документа создать таймер, который подождёт загрузку страницы секунд 20, например, или меньше. А потом покажет рекламу. Тогда этот код сработает 1 раз.

Comment: я пробовал через new Timer, и у меня приложение упало, правда я это в onCreate написал.